# Accessing css variable on mount in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a Vue.js PWA that requires the js to know the value of `env(safe-area-inset-top)`. I have the `env` reassigned to a css variable named `--sat` which I'm reading. But I can't find a way to get its value at the beginning of the lifecycle.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) says that

> The Window `load` event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as **stylesheets** and images.

So i've tried the following:

```js
methods: {
  setSat() {
    this.sat = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--sat');
  },
},
mounted() {
  window.onload = this.setSat;
},
```

However this doesn't seem to work. When I open the project on my phone from the home screen as a PWA the `setSat` method does get called by itself but returns `0px`. If I trigger it by clicking a button after the page is loaded it returns the appropriate `48px`.

If I try to run the function on a 0 or even 100ms timeout, the value of `env(safe-area-inset-top)` is still `0px`.

For now I've resorted to waiting a second before getting the value but this is obviously not desirable.

[Repo with minimal code for reproduction](https://github.com/anatolykopyl/pwa-question)

Answer (score 0):

I could not consistently reproduce the issue even cloning your repo, but here are some potential issues I've spotted in your code:

- You are assigning the onload callback only after the component has been mounted. This is potentially an issue, since your component might be mounted after the website is loaded and therefore the event is not tiggered. There should be an explicit check if the page is already loaded and call the method right away.
- Assigning the callback to `window.onload` might also create issues if several components are competing for that callback. addEventListener and removeEventListener is a safer way.
- Using a 1 second delay might not be a good solution, but there's no harm in delaying the style computation one tick by using `this.$nextTick`.

This is a new version of your code with all these fixes:

```
  methods: {
    setSat() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.sat = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--sat');
      })
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.setSat();
      });
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', this.setSat);
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('load', this.setSat);
  },
```

Comment: Did you manage to get a non zero value for ‘—sat’ on load?